# Adding data from PHP to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

First of all i'm sorry if this duplicate topics. However i've tried many solution but still failed. 
Basically i want to add input data to mysql table. At first, all the input is blank when click submit. After few round of try and error, i manage to have input data key in to the db table but certain column still empty. need you guys help how can i fix this.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "alltest123";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Get values from form 
$ixname=($_POST['ixp']);
$peername=($_POST['test2']);
$asname=($_POST['asname']);
$ipv4=($_POST['ipv4']);
$ipv6=($_POST['ipv6']);
$descr=($_POST['test3']);
$node=($_POST['node']);
$category=($_POST['category']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_peer (ixname, peername, asname, ipv4, ipv6, descr, node, category)
VALUES ('$ixp', '$test2', '$asname', '$ipv4', '$ipv6', '$test3', '$node', '$category')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

form.php

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Test Form </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="71">IX Name</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="301"><input name="ixp" type="text" id="ixp"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peer Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="test2" type="text" id="test2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ASN</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="asname" type="text" id="asname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ipv4 Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="ipv4" type="text" id="ipv4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ipv6 Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="ipv6" type="text" id="ipv6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="test3" type="text" id="test3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Node</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="node" type="text" id="node"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="category" type="text" id="category"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP and MYSQL version

```
PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 11:36:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0+deb9u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Error Logs

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ixp in /var/www/insert_ac.php on line 25, referer: testb.php
PHP Stack trace:, referer:testb.php
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/insert_ac.php:0, referer: testb.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: test2 in /var/www/insert_ac.php on line 25, referer: testb.php
PHP Stack trace:, referer: testb.php
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/insert_ac.php:0, referer: testb.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: test3 in /var/www/insert_ac.php on line 25, referer:testb.php
PHP Stack trace:, referer: testb.php
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/insert_ac.php:0, referer: testb.php
```

Comment: It says in the error log, that the variable 'ixp' is undefined. On the top you define it as  $ixname. ($ixname=($_POST['ixp']);) You might change it in the sql query. The same with 'test2' and 'test3'. ($sql = "INSERT INTO [...] VALUES ($ixname, $peername, ...))

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo's really. You have moved data from the POST array into scalar variables, but then used the wrong variable names in the INSERT query

```
$ixname=($_POST['ixp']);
$peername=($_POST['test2']);
$descr=($_POST['test3']);
```

query

```
VALUES ('$ixp', '$test2', '$asname', '$ipv4', '$ipv6', '$test3', '$node', '$category')";
         ^^^     ^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^
```

> I have to warn you that Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 1):

You are not using correct variables. You should change your SQL query like below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_peer (ixname, peername, asname, ipv4, ipv6, descr, node, category)
    VALUES ('$ixname', '$peername', '$asname', '$ipv4', '$ipv6', '$descr', '$node', '$category')";
```

Also, you should bind your variables in SQL query to avoid SQL injection. Check link for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey instead of storing all values in a respective variable just use **extract()** method which will give your result.

```
// Get values from form 
extract($_POST);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_peer (ixname, peername, asname, ipv4, ipv6, descr, node, category)
VALUES ('$ixp', '$test2', '$asname', '$ipv4', '$ipv6', '$test3', '$node', '$category')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

For more reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php